# Does a D minor vocal work in a G minor production?

Tags: theory, chord-theory, electronic-music

Please help. The vocal is coming up D minor. The track with the vocal is showing G minor. But the vocals sound off. Do these keys work well together or not?

-Coming up in tunebat analyzer that is.

-Showing in the tunebat analyzer results, to clarify.
I looked up the key of the vocals vs the production using the tunebat dot com analyzer.

Comment: I don't fully understand your question but can say a couple things: "work" or "work well together" are subjective. Listen to what you've got and if you like it, then you're fine. If you don't like it, then you probably want to figure out what to change to help you like it more. Second point, almost all but the simplest music has some kind of chromaticism, meaning all the notes are not in the same key or mode all the time. D minor and G minor are very similar so if you smash them together there are many ways that it can sound good and maybe a few ways it can sound not good.

Comment: Are you using some type of analyzing software or loops labeled with keys? Your question is very vague and will probably be closed if you are not more specific.

Comment: What do “coming up” and “showing” mean here? Are you using some kind of external tool to determine tonalities? Please edit to clarify.

Comment: This is a typical budding EDM producer producer question.  You are allowed to use any loop on top of any other loop.  It turns out that this combination sounds bad, though, so you probably should not use it.